# Можно ли использовать шаблонные строки с объектом classList для вызова методо remove и add по условию?

Tags: javascript

Для того чтобы не использовать два практически одинаковых цикла с if else для выделения всех строк в таблице и снятия выделения пытаюсь использовать несколько вложенных выражений в шаблонной строке. Пример ниже в 4 строке кода
Пробовал много вариантов - не получается. Может этот случай не сработает?
Метот classList.toggle('table-active') не подходит.

```
rows.forEach(row => {
  const checkbox = row.querySelector('i')
  const condition = this.selectedRows.length === rows.length

  `row.classList.${condition ? 'remove' : 'add'}('table-active')`

   checkbox.textContent = condition ? '' : '✓'
 })
 this.selectedRows = document.querySelectorAll('.table tbody tr.table-active')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно у объекта обращаться не через точку, а через квадратные скобки. Будет примерно такое:

```js
let element = document.getElementById('test');
let method = getMethod();
element.classList[method]('testy');
              // ^^^^^^^^
setTimeout(() => {  
  let method = getMethod(false);
  element.classList[method]('testy');
                // ^^^^^^^^
}, 2000);


function getMethod(flag = true) {
  return flag ? 'add' : 'remove';
}
```

```css
.testy {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю что в данном случае игра стоит свеч. Всегда следует стремиться к понятности кода, если `if/else` c однострочниками можно записать в 2 строки.

Посмотрите, количество строк столько же сколько и в вопросе, однако нет никаких хитрых действий, если и можно ругать этот код то только за форматирование `if/else`, но не к такому сокращению строк нужно стремиться, следует избегать излишнего исполнения кода, надуманности в необходимости некоторых функций и конструкций:

```js
rows.forEach(row => {
  const checkbox = row.querySelector('i')

  if (this.selectedRows.length === rows.length) row.classList.add('table-active')
  else row.classList.remove('table-active')

  checkbox.textContent = condition ? '' : '✓'
})
this.selectedRows = document.querySelectorAll('.table tbody tr.table-active')
```

Если же хочется применить шаблонные строки, то можно применять например так:

```
element.className = `${conditon ? 'active' : ''} other_class`
```

Таким образом шаблонная строка подставит либо имя класса либо строку нулевой длины, остальные классы можно прописать по другим условиям либо захардкодить если они не меняются.

Comment: На самом деле    проще использовать тернарник и element.classList.toggle %))